# Why does the spring joint plugin not work?

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I followed the example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/19ae3a34ec8e5ce126f62da3fd6c9e59f29c73bb/test/plugins/SpringTestPlugin.cc) and created a model plugin, that at each update call this function:

```
  void SpringJointPlugin::OnUpdate()
  {
    this->current_angle = this->joint_ptr_->GetAngle(0).Radian();
    this->joint_ptr_->SetForce( 0, (this->rest_angle-this->current_angle)*this->stiffness);
  }
```

the `joint_ptr_` is of `physics::JointPtr` format. When I try to build this plugin, I get error

```
SpringJointPlugin.cc:80:45: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘GetAngle’; did you mean ‘GetForce’?
     this->current_angle = this->joint_ptr_->GetAngle(0).Radian();
                                             ^~~~~~~~
                                             GetForce
```

When I look into [the documentation](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/2.2.1/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html), this method is listed. When I use the the `GetForce` method as suggested, or any other function listed in the documentation, it still gives me errors.

Why and how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21289/why-does-the-spring-joint-plugin-not-work?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2018-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You're looking at the documentation for Gazebo 2, but I suspect you're not using that version. Take a look at the [migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/annotate/173b2e9038766bb20fd16468c74465ff64355411/Migration.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Migration.md-475), the new function from Gazebo 8 is `Joint::Position`.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2018-12-10**:
Is there no up-to-date documentation for Gazebo 9?